# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u015f' in position 21: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, character-encoding, praw

So, I am running a script that takes posts from reddit and tweets them out. Some of these posts contain latin-1 characters.

`print post.encode('latin-1') + " " + post_dict[post].encode('latin-1') + " #python"`

This prints out the character **ê** perfectly fine. However, it will not print out the character [**ş**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/15f/index.htm), as you can see in the link it is Latin-1.

Script code:

```
import praw
import json
import requests
import tweepy
import time

access_token = 'REDACTED'
access_token_secret = 'REDACTED'
consumer_key = 'REDACTED'
consumer_secret = 'REDACTED'

def strip_title(title):
    if len(title) < 94:
        return title
    else:
        return title[:93] + "..."

def tweet_creator(subreddit_info):
    post_dict = {}
    post_ids = []
    print "[bot] Getting posts from Reddit"
    for submission in subreddit_info.get_hot(limit=20):
        post_dict[strip_title(submission.title)] = submission.url
        post_ids.append(submission.id)
    print "[bot] Generating short link using goo.gl"
    mini_post_dict = {}
    for post in post_dict:
        post_title = post
        post_link = post_dict[post]         
        short_link = shorten(post_link)
        mini_post_dict[post_title] = short_link 
    return mini_post_dict, post_ids

def setup_connection_reddit(subreddit):
    print "[bot] setting up connection with Reddit"
    r = praw.Reddit('yasoob_python reddit twitter bot '
                'monitoring %s' %(subreddit)) 
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit(subreddit)
    return subreddit

def shorten(url):
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    payload = {"longUrl": url}
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    link = json.loads(r.text)['id']
    return link

def duplicate_check(id):
    found = 0
    with open('posted_posts.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if id in line:
                found = 1
    return found

def add_id_to_file(id):
    with open('posted_posts.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(id) + "\n")

def main():
    subreddit = setup_connection_reddit(‘python’)
    post_dict, post_ids = tweet_creator(subreddit)
    tweeter(post_dict, post_ids)

def tweeter(post_dict, post_ids):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    for post, post_id in zip(post_dict, post_ids):
        found = duplicate_check(post_id)
        if found == 0:
            print "[bot] Posting this link on twitter"
           print post.encode('latin-1') + " " + post_dict[post].encode('latin-1') + " #python"
            api.update_status(post+" "+post_dict[post]+" #python")
            add_id_to_file(post_id)
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            print "[bot] Already posted" 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "twitter.py", line 83, in <module>
main()
File "twitter.py", line 64, in main
tweeter(post_dict, post_ids)
File "twitter.py", line 74, in tweeter
print post.encode('latin-1') + " " + post_dict[post].encode('latin-1') + " #python"  
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u015f' in position 21:    
ordinal not in range(256)
```

**Note: I am a python beginner, and I am trying to learn it.**

Comment: Which part of the link? The part that says "Latin Extended-A"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"S with cedilla" is not in [latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

You're probably looking for [ISO_8859-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), [ISO_8859-9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9), or maybe even [windows-1254](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254).

Comment: Correct. Using windows-1254. Thanks!